# Postgres and php connection

Tags: php, postgresql

I have problem with `Postgres.app`. `Postgres.app` is running without problems in mac os x EI Captain.

but in my `phpinfo()` I can see.

PDO drivers => `mysql`, `sqlite` but not able to see pgsql

when I run commat php -m I can see:

```
pod_mysql
do_sqlite
```

Please help me in connecting pgsql with php.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using xampp (lampp in linux), enable php_pgsql.dll which is already came along with xampp, try to edit the php.ini and remove the semicolon before

```
extension = php_pgsql.dll
```

Now restart your Apache server.

Or, you can use native function, see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php) for Documentation.